# Django-import-export not importing csv or excel file with ForeignKey attribute in The Django admin site panel

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin, django-import-export

I am using the Django-import-export module in Django(version 4.0.1).

I have 2 different tables named `State` and `District`

the `district model` is using `state_name` as `ForeignKey`

The fields in state table can be imported from the `Django admin site panel` without any issue  as:
[image: state]

but district attributes can not be imported via csv/excel file and the error is as follows:

```
Line number: 1 - 'id'
ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLANDS, NICOBARS
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python_Abhilash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 667, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "C:\Python_Abhilash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 359, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "C:\Python_Abhilash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 346, in get_instance
import_id_fields = [
File "C:\Python_Abhilash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 347, in <listcomp>
self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_id_fields()
KeyError: 'id'
```

The `model.py` is as:

```
from django.db import models

####################################################################################
class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'State_Names'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_name
####################################################################################
class District(models.Model):
    state_name = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    district_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'District_Names'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.district_name
```

The `resources.py` is as:

```
from import_export import fields, resources
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget
from damuwhatsapp.models import State
from damuwhatsapp.models import District


class StateResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = State

class DistrictResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class StateForeignKeyWiget(ForeignKeyWidget):
        def get_queryset(self, value, row):
            return self.model.objects.filter(
                state_name__exact=row["state_name"],
            )

    state_name = fields.Field(
        column_name='state_name',
        attribute='state_name',
        widget=StateForeignKeyWiget(
            State,
            field='state_name'
        )
    )
    
    district_name = fields.Field(column_name="district_name", attribute="district_name")

    class Meta:
        model = District
        exclude = ('id')
        fields = ('state_name','district_name',)
```

The `admin.py` is as:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin 
from damuwhatsapp.models import State
from damuwhatsapp.models import District
from damuwhatsapp.resources import StateResource
from damuwhatsapp.resources import DistrictResource

class StateAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = StateResource
    list_display = ("id", 
                    "state_name")
    search_fields = ["state_name"]
    readonly_fields = ["id"]
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldset = ()

class DistrictAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = DistrictResource
    list_display = ["id",
                    "state_name",
                    "district_name"]
    search_fields = ("state_name", 
                    "district_name")

    readonly_fields = ["id"]
    
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldset = ()

admin.site.register(State, StateAdmin)
admin.site.register(District, DistrictAdmin)
```

I need to import the csv having district_name which uses state_names as ForeignKey field from Django Admin Panel. [I have followed few question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66611123/django-import-export-problem-importing-foreignkey-field) like but could not find the solution. Can you have a look at the code and see which part I am doing wrong or needs to be changed?
Or what is the alternate option for doing so.

The CSV file structure which is to be imported is as.

[image]

admin panel:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `DistrictResource` you exclude the 'id' field and do not declare 'import_id_fields'- so the 'district' import process cannot detect whether you are importing a new or existing instance.

You probably want to add `import_id_fields = ('state_name','district_name')` to `DistrictResource` meta declaration.

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69347073/39296).